# Come ridono gli italiani?

Tags: single-words, interjections

Gli ispanoparlanti abbiamo la ‘i lunga’ [j] e la ‘a’ [a] per esprimere una risata per iscritto — in chat, contesto informale — sia *con* qualcuno o *di* qualcuno.

Esempio di risata *con* qualcuno:

> — Ricordi la prima volta che prendemmo una sbronza? 
> — [*Jajajaja*], sì, fu stupendo!

Esempio di risata *di* qualcuno:

> — Mi hanno buttato fuori dalla discoteca.
> — [*Jajajaja*]! Ti avevo detto di falsificare il documento!

In alcune occasioni usiamo anche ‘je’ per esprimere una risata ‘tesa’: in realtà chi ride così è pauroso e intenta rilassarsi. Esempio di risata ‘tesa’:

> — Figlio, rientri adesso!? Dove sei stato!?
> — [*Jejejeje*], la notte si è prolungata...

In altri casi, possiamo fare una risata ‘sottile’ con ‘xd’ (in minuscola, per favore!). Non è facile spiegare, però la si usa soprattutto quando immaginiamo una situazione bizzarra senza esaltarci:

> — Non avete più spazio per me in macchina? 
> — Posso portarti nel baule xd.

Strettamente, la ‘i lunga’ non è una lettera italiana. Allora: Che consonante usate? Acca, come in inglese? Usate le vocale ‘a’ e ‘e’? Usate altre vocali? Usate ‘xd’ o è considerato un anglicismo? Grazie per i chiarimenti sull'uso della risata nella scrittura, o l'uso della scrittura nella risata, come preferite.

Comment: Adesso scrivo una risposta, ma un piccolo appunto grammaticale: gli italiani *ridono*, non *si ridono* :).

Comment: Mi sono permesso di limare qualche punto del tuo italiano. Per favore controlla che non abbia frainteso qualcosa. In particolare, non sono sicuro di cosa intendevi nello scambio di battute sul documento falso.

Comment: @DaG Grazie per limare il mio italiano. Nel secondo dialogo, un ragazzo che è minorenne vuole entrare nella discoteca. Un amico gli dice di falsificare il suo documento, ma lui non gli obbedisce. Poi all'ingresso del disco mostra il suo documento, però è espulso. Nella chat telefonica (con l'amico):  ‘-Me rebotaron en la entrada. -¡Jajajaja! ¡Te dije que falsificaras tu documento!’ , o in inglese '-I have been kicked out at the entrance. - Hahahaha! I told you should have falsified your document!’. (congiuntivo)

Comment: Benissimo, @tac, grazie. Allora avevo capito bene.

Comment: Ridono a voce "hahaha" e in testo lo scrivono "ahahah".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L’interezione *ah* ripetuta, *ah ah ah!*, è il modo di esprimere la risata  classica, standard:

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ah/

Ma c’è anche *eh eh eh*, che può rappresentare una risata ironica:

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/eh/

O anche  *ih ih ih*, che   può rappresentare una risata  sardonica, cattiva, un ghigno:

*dalla bocca ... gli venne fuori con suono stridulo e imbrogliato il ritornello d’una canzonettaccia francese ... seguìto da un ghigno: ih ih ih ih* (Pirandello).

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ih/

Comment: Noi usiamo anche ‘ji’. [C'è un brano con questo nome (ji ji ji)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVMFsnBxdME)

Comment: A proposito di xd, quello non è italiano né è un anglicismo, è un' emoticon che si usa su internet o nei messaggi. Sì, lo usiamo, ma in genere scritto XD. È una emoticon in cui X sarebbero gli occhi e D la bocca che ride. Grazie per l'accettazione della domanda : -)

Answer (score 3):

La trascrizione standard della risata in italiano sia "ahahah", vedi ad esempio [questo articolo dell'Inkiesta](https://www.linkiesta.it/2018/02/tutti-i-modi-in-cui-viene-scritto-il-suono-della-risata-nel-mondo/). A volte si vede la grafia "hahaha", influenzata dall'inglese.

Nota che la lettera *j* esiste in italiano (anche se è molto poco usata, più che altro in toponimi), ma ha un suono diverso dallo spagnolo (dove, se capisco bene, suona /h/) e si pronuncia /j/, cioè il suono all'inizio della parola inglese "yes", per cui "jajaja" non funzionerebbe in italiano.

Per quanto riguarda "xdxdxd" non l'ho mai visto usare in italiano.